# orderBy doesn't work with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Am using orderBy to sort my  objects by their startdate.

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item  ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy: e.startdate">
 <h4>{{e.name}}</h4>
 <h4>{{e.startdate}}</h4>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But it doen't work , how can i fix it please

Comment: Try `orderBy: 'startdate'`.

Comment: it works perfectly thankx

Answer (score 3):

By this:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item  ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy: 'startdate'">
 <h4>{{e.name}}</h4>
 <h4>{{e.startdate}}</h4>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<ion-item  ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy: startdate">`
Because each ng-repeat has its own scope and you are already in the scope of e when orderBy evaluates.

Comment: thankx :))  i add '' to startdate and it works well :))